# Numpy compatibility issue on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda, aws-data-wrangler

I need to use [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler), NumPy and SciPy in one AWS Lambda.

To make it possible I use two Layers:

- Layer provided by AWS: `AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x` - AWS Lambda SciPy Layer for Python38 (scipy-1.5.1, numpy-1.19.0)
- Custom Layer created from [awswrangler-layer-2.9.0-py3.8.zip](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/releases/tag/2.9.0)

My AWS Lambda function looks like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import awswrangler as wr
```

And the error I receive:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
[ERROR] ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I there a way I could make it work?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible somehow?

Comment: @Gulzar, isn't this reproducible? Create a Lambda with code like shown, add two above Layers and run. You should get the error.

Comment: What should I copy-paste and run? How to call it? What to install and *exactly* how? Maybe I am not following, but I don't think this can be easily reproduced without some setup.

Comment: @Gulzar In AWS Console find Lambda, click _create_, in the _Code_ tab paste those two lines of code. At the bottom there is a menu called _Layers_ where you have a GUI to add those Layers. Then click a green _Test_ button. There's not really much more to it.

Comment: I still get this too - any advance on it?